# Orientação a Objetos e valores sem sentido em c++

Tags: c, c++, orientação-a-objetos, struct

Olá, estou começando na programação em c++ e resolvi fazer uma struct para aprender e tal... só que o compilador não mostra nenhum erro e no final o programa me mostra um valor completamente sem sentido,quero dizer, enquanto o valor esperado para "maiorprec" é  7 o programa me mostra 1878038440. Eu queria a ajuda de alguma alma caridosa pq fiquei batendo a cabeça por um longo tempo e não encontrei o motivo.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Apart{
    int preco;     // variáveis utilizadas no código
    string nome;
    string local;
    int quartos;
    int area;
    float pedireito;
    bool mobilhado;
    int tamprec,tamnome,tamarea;  // aramazenam o numero de algarismos (ou letras) de preco nome e local

    void insere(int precoin,string nomein,string localin,int quartosin,int areain,float pedireitoin,bool mobilhadoin){
        precoin=preco;
        nomein=nome;
        localin=local;
        quartosin=quartos;     // função utilizada para armazenar os valores mais facilmente
        areain=area;
        pedireitoin=pedireito;
        mobilhadoin=mobilhado;
    }

    void tamanho(){
    while(preco){
        preco=preco/10;
        tamprec++;
     }                        // conseguindo e aramazenando o numero de algarismos em tamprec tamarea e tamnome

     while(area){
        area=area/10;
        tamarea++;
     }
     while(nome[tamnome]!='/0'){
        tamnome++;
     }

   }
};

int main(){
    int qtap=5; //quantidade de aparttamentos
    Apart ap[qtap];
    ap[0].insere(1000000,"tremenda","goiania",3,300,3.5,1);
    ap[1].insere(2000000,"rosas","sao paulo",4,500,4,0);
    ap[2].insere(150000,"tricola","fortaleza",2,275,2,1);    // inserindo os valores
    ap[3].insere(300000,"art4","palmas",4,290,2.5,0);
    ap[4].insere(40000,"aurelia","rio de janeiro",1,100,2,1);
    for(int i;i<qtap;i++){ap[i].tamanho();}  // chamando a funçao tamanho para cada objeto


    int maioprec=ap[0].tamprec;
    int maioarea=ap[0].tamarea;
    int maionome=ap[0].tamnome;

    for(int i=1;i<qtap;i++){          // comparando os valores de tamprec e imprimindo o maior deles
    if(maioprec<ap[i].tamprec){
        maioprec=ap[i].tamprec;
        }
    }
    cout<<maioprec;  // porém eu acabo com um valor completamente sem sentido, alguém sabe o por quê?
}
```

OBS: eu utilizei o dev-c++ e o code blocks (nsei, talvez tenha alguma coisa a ver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucas, o erro que você está cometendo é na hora de iniciar os atributos da sua estrutura.

Note que ao invés de iniciar os atributos como `preco`, `nome` e `local`, você está reatribuindo os argumentos da função (`precoin`, `nomein`, `localin`) com os valores não iniciados da sua estrutura.

Outra coisa: apesar de "funcionar", a forma com a qual você calcula os tamanhos do preço, area e nome é terrível, pois você não está iniciando esses valores com 0, está alterando os valores de `preco` e `area` durante o processo, e esses valores só são calculados se você se lembrar de invocar o método `tamanho`, o que é contra-intuitivo e torna seu código suscetível a erros.

Idealmente você deveria utilizar métodos para calcular esses valores, assim, não importa quando os valores de `preco`, `nome` e `area` forem alterados, os tamanho desses valores sempre irão condizer com o valor do atributo, pois tal tamanho é calculado no momento que você o busca na sua estrutura.

Então, concertando o "construtor" da sua estrutura:

```
void insere(int precoin, string nomein, string localin, int quartosin, int areain, float pedireitoin, bool mobilhadoin) {
    preco = precoin;
    nome = nomein;
    local = localin;
    quartos = quartosin;
    area = areain;
    pedireito = pedireitoin;
    mobilhado = mobilhadoin;
}
```

E concertando a forma de calcular o tamanho dos atributos:

```
int tamprec() {
    return to_string(preco).length();
}

int tamarea() {
    return to_string(area).length();
}

int tamnome() {
    return nome.length();
}
```

Você teria o código completo funcionando corretamente:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Apart {
    // atributos utilizadas no código
    int preco;
    string nome;
    string local;
    int quartos;
    int area;
    float pedireito;
    bool mobilhado;

    // função utilizada para armazenar os valores mais facilmente
    void insere(int precoin, string nomein, string localin, int quartosin, int areain, float pedireitoin, bool mobilhadoin) {
        preco = precoin;
        nome = nomein;
        local = localin;
        quartos = quartosin;
        area = areain;
        pedireito = pedireitoin;
        mobilhado = mobilhadoin;
    }

    int tamprec() {
        return to_string(preco).length();
    }

    int tamarea() {
        return to_string(area).length();
    }

    int tamnome() {
        return nome.length();
    }
};

int main() {
    //quantidade de apartamentos
    int qtap = 5;
    Apart ap[qtap];

    // inserindo os valores
    ap[0].insere(1000000, "tremenda", "goiania",        3, 300, 3.5, 1);
    ap[1].insere(2000000, "rosas",    "sao paulo",      4, 500, 4,   0);
    ap[2].insere(150000,  "tricola",  "fortaleza",      2, 275, 2,   1);
    ap[3].insere(300000,  "art4",     "palmas",         4, 290, 2.5, 0);
    ap[4].insere(40000,   "aurelia",  "rio de janeiro", 1, 100, 2,   1);

    int maioprec = ap[0].tamprec();
    int maioarea = ap[0].tamarea();
    int maionome = ap[0].tamnome();

    // comparando os valores de tamprec e imprimindo o maior deles
    for (int i = 1; i < qtap; i++) {
        if (maioprec < ap[i].tamprec()) {
            maioprec = ap[i].tamprec();
        }
    }

    cout << maioprec;
}
```